# Подключение к mysql в laravel/sail, работая в wsl2

Tags: mysql, laravel, docker, wsl2

Имею в файле .env проекта на ларавель/sail следующие настройки для подключения к mysql в контейнере sail:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=myapp
DB_USERNAME=sail
DB_PASSWORD=password
```

Миграции выполняются, все отлично. Но при попытке сделать запрос в бд выдает ошибку

`SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (Connection: mysql, SQL: select * from` users`where`email `= мой маил в бд limit 1).`

3 дня рыл гугл. Советуют установить DB_HOST=mysql или localhost. Но в данных случаял при попытке php artisan migrate в уже в консоли выдает ошибку

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo for mysql failed: Name or service not known (Connection: mysql, SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = myapp and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')
```

Пробовал уже и сносить полностью как проект, так и убунту c wsl, artisan cash clear, обновлять composer. Ничего не помогает. В первом варианте- миграции проходят, но выдает ошибку refused при запросе, в других вариантах- даже миграции не проходят.

Помогите плжста выяснить, в чем дело. Драйвера в php все установлены.

Comment: `FORWARD_DB_PORT=3306` добавьте

Comment: @InDevX добавил, не помогло. Установил через sail контейнер с pqsql. В этот раз, если прописывать localhost, уже видит, но при запросе к бд все равно выбрасывает QLSTATE[08006] [7] connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: Connection refused Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections? connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: Cannot assign requested address Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections? (Connection: pgsql, SQL: select * from "users" where "email" = vladislav-an0@rambler.ru limit 1).

Comment: `DB_HOST=postgres` такой хост попробуйте, если pgsql то FORWARD_DB_PORT тоже 5432

Comment: @InDevX увы, вновь  SQLSTATE[08006] [7] could not translate host name "postgres" to address: Name or service not known (Connection: pgsql и т.д. В том и дело, работает, точнее, позволяет делать миграции только 127.0.0.1 на msql , + localhost на постгрес. Да и то, при подключении пробрасывает refused. Уже отчаялся, в общем, 3 дня бьюсь с этим. Не судьба видимо с sail и wsl работать. т.к. нервы не стальные. Спасибо за ответ)

Comment: @InDevX + горит еще от того, что самый первый раз, когда я все ставил и запускал, оно коннектилось и запросы проходили без проблем. Потом просто слетело на след день, и я хз, в чем причина.

Comment: Bсегда чисто docker-compose.yml под проект собираю, не юзал ещё sail

Answer (score 0):

Поменяйте в .env файле

DB_HOST=mysql